# Rewrite rules ignoring my dist folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

So I have a bunch of .htaccess rules for my angular application and I'm looking for the behavior:

> If dist/frontend.html exists, route everything to that. If not route to frontend.html.

This is what I currently have. The rules work as long as I'm requesting a sub route (e.g. http://www.domain.com/404/) but if I'm requesting the root, with no path it's like these rules are never executed and it just relies on the `DirectoryIndex`.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html frontend.html index.php

# Rewrite everything which looks like it should be handled by angular here, 404 if a specific resource
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|css|js|html)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dist/frontend.html -f
RewriteRule ^ dist/frontend.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|css|js|html)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/frontend.html -f
RewriteRule ^ frontend.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|css|js|html)$ [NC]
```

Since you're ignoring `.html` extension and also using `index.html` as default handler using `DirectoryIndex` causing both of your rules to be skipped.

If you're going to use one of the `frontend.html` using one of the 2 rules then you don't really need `DirectoryIndex` directive, just **comment it out** and it should work.

Comment: Already tried that I'm afraid. You're on the right track but commenting out the DirectoryIndex just results in a directory listing on my localhost.

Comment: OK then just have this line for DirectoryIndex. `DirectoryIndex frontend.html` replacing your existing one.